# Can alternate language versions rely on canonicals to satisfy the requirement to point back to the original page?

Tags: seo, google, canonical-url, language, rel-alternate

Say I have 4 URLs:

1. `www.example.com/en/main-content`
2. `www.example.com/en/almost-identical-to-main-content`
3. `www.example.com/fr/main-content`
4. `www.example.com/fr/almost-identical-to-main-content`

The second URL in the list has a canonical tag to the first URL in the list, and the fourth URL in the list has a canonical tag to the third URL in the list.

In terms of Languages, URL's `3` and `1` are alternate versions of each other, and so are `4` and `2`.

Google require that each `alternate` version have a two way tag, one from each page pointing to the other one. Is URL `2` allowed to point its `alternate` tag to URL `3`, as URL `3` anyway has a canonical to URL `4`, or must it point at URL `4`?

Comment: Canonicals should used for duplicate pages (at least 90% duplicate), not for similar pages.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller they are 95% duplicate, just one small difference. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical+hreflang markup for your urls should be like:

www.example.com/en/main-content

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.example.com/en/main-content">
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com/en/main-content" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com/fr/main-content" hreflang="fr" />
```

www.example.com/en/similar-to-main-content

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.example.com/en/main-content">
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com/en/similar-to-main-content" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com/fr/similar-to-main-content" hreflang="fr" />
```

www.example.com/fr/main-content

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.example.com/fr/main-content">
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com/en/main-content" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com/fr/main-content" hreflang="fr" />
```

www.example.com/fr/similar-to-main-content

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.example.com/fr/main-content">
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com/en/similar-to-main-content" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="www.example.com/fr/similar-to-main-content" hreflang="fr" />
```

Canonicals are for canonicalization, hreflangs are for exact interlinking of multilanguage structure - don't mix their goals!

Comment: Thanks for this, is this from your experience or is this actually documented somewhere. I would have thought that as they are Canonicalised, you should be able to point to any of the URLs. I agree that your version makes a lot of sense semantically.

Comment: :) both - from Google's documentation and from experience. Indeed, you _could_ point your hreflangs from the canonicalized urls to canonical too. It would make more sense in terms of canonicalization. But, thinking straightly, it would give Google wrong signal - because in this case hreflangs would point not to exactly corresponding language version. We have to deal with the machine - thats why i always prefer to send mostly clearly interpretable  signals. Don't overestimate Google - its just a robot. Sending mixed signals we are at risc, that all of our signals will be ignored.